# Passing multiple GET variables in load()?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML Form that is not wrapped in a 'form' tag. There are only inputs which are then passed through GET with JQuery's load() method.

This is how it's coded it works.

```
$("#loader").load("mail.php", {
            name: $("input[name=name]").val(),
            email: $("input[name=email]").val(),
            phone: $("input[name=phone]").val(),
            city: $("input[name=city]").val(),
            subject: $("input[name=subject]").val(),
            message: $("textarea[name=message]").val()
        });
```

Question: Is there a way to pass all inputs to the load() method without having to write each one of them?

Something like this:

```
$("#loader").load("mail.php", allinputs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a parent container with all those items called 'container'.

```
$('.container').click(function(){
    var allInputs = $('.container :input').serialize();
    $('#loader').load('mail.php', allInputs);
});
```

[Something like this will probably help you get far.](http://jsfiddle.net/CCKra/)

Comment: I need it to be POST instead of GET. Any way to do this?